# How to install biganalytics_1.1.3 package in R3.1.0?

Tags: r, package, installation, r-bigmemory

Please help, I cannot install biganalytics_1.1.3 in my windows 7 32-bit system

```
library(biganalytics)

Error: package ‘biganalytics’ is not installed for 'arch = i386'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘biganalytics’ was built under R version 3.1.1
```

I even tried the following command in cmd prompt

```
R CMD INSTALL --build biganalytics_1.1.3.tar.gz
```

It's showing error

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'biganalytics'
```

Also with the option `install.package`

```
install.packages("D:\\DataMining\\Rpackages\\biganalytics_1.1.3.zip",repos=NULL)

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/859673/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘biganalytics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

library(biganalytics)

Error: package ‘biganalytics’ is not installed for 'arch = i386'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘biganalytics’ was built under R version 3.1.1
```

It is still showing the same error

Comment: Your R version is 3.1.0. The error message states that `package ‘biganalytics’ was built under R version 3.1.1`. I suggest that you update your R version (the current version is 3.2.2).

Comment: thanks RHertel ,I will do that but I don't think that's the problem because bigmemory and bigalgebra got installed successfully